# addClass('active') on this doesn't seem to work appropriately

Tags: jquery, html, css

`$(this).addClass('active')` does not work

I am stuck in some code where I try to add active class but the code doesn't seem to work fine.

I tried a couple of ways but couldn't resolve It works fine if I add an !important at the end of CSS but I don't like to use.

It's the first time I am writing jquery any additional code improvement suggestions will also help.

```js
var obj = [{
    firstName: 'Chakradhari',
    lastName: 'Jamili',
    errorProne: true,
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Nikitha',
    lastName: 'Mandadi',
    errorProne: false,
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jyothi',
    lastName: 'Madala',
    errorProne: true,
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Mahesh',
    lastName: 'Pola',
    errorProne: false,
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Maheswari',
    lastName: 'Poli',
    errorProne: false,
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Maheswari',
    lastName: 'Poli',
    errorProne: false,
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var view = $('#todaysFlow');
  var move = '100px';

  if (obj.length > 5) {
    $(".arrow").css('display', 'block');
    $(".right").click(function() {
      view
        .stop(false, true)
        .animate({
          left: '-=' + move
        }, {
          duration: 400
        })
    });

    $(".left").click(function() {
      console.log(parseInt(view.css('left')))
      if (parseInt(view.css('left')) <= 0) {
        view
          .stop(false, true)
          .animate({
            left: '+=' + move
          }, {
            duration: 400
          })
      }

    });
  }


  obj.forEach(function(obj, i) {
    var div = $('<div>')
    var p = $('<p>')
    var errorSpan = $('<span>');
    var elems = $('.todaysFlow div')

    div.click(function() {
        $('#displayContent').html(obj.firstName[0] + ' ' + obj.lastName[0]);
        elems.not(this).removeClass('active');
        $('.error_exclamation').remove();

        /*
         This active class doesn't seem to work fine even though color is being added      but border is getting striken away I am guessing it has something to do         with presidence.
        */
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if (obj.errorProne) {
          errorSpan.addClass('error_exclamation');
          $(this).append(errorSpan);
        }
      })
      .addClass('generate_div_css');

    p.addClass('generate_div_p_css')
      .html(obj.firstName[0] + ' ' + obj.lastName[0]);
    div.append(p)
    $('#todaysFlow').append(div);

    if (i == 0) {
      div.click();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.mainDiv {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* This is the active class is being used which isn't affective */

.active {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.arrow {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: none;
}

.left {
  left: 0
}

.left::before {
  content: '\227A'
}

.right {
  right: 0
}

.right::after {
  content: '\227B'
}

.peopleInfo {
  width: 410px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.todaysFlow {
  width: 1200px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}


/* This is the css I have used for styling the div's */

.generate_div_css {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.generate_div_p_css {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13%;
  left: 34%;
  margin-right: -34%;
}

.random {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.error_exclamation {
  position: absolute;
  background: orange;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
}

.error_exclamation::before {
  content: '1'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="arrow left"></div>
  <div class="peopleInfo">
    <div id="todaysFlow" class="todaysFlow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow right"></div>
</div>
<div id="displayContent"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Chakradhari/ecm3foxr/114/

Please help me improve my code. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addClass()` call is working fine in your code - as you can see from the fact that the text color of the `div` changes to blue.

The problem is because the `border` styling in the `.active` class is not of a high enough precedence to override the default styling in `.generate_div_css`. To fix the problem, make the `.active` class more specific:

```
.generate_div_css.active {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tobcqhy1/)

Comment: I think only a circle should be blue at once?

Comment: @HappyCoding that's down to the OP's logic. If you click the divs from left to right then the previous is deselected, if you go right to left then they are not.